# How to use macro as a macro variable in dbt

Tags: sql, presto, dbt, amazon-athena

I'm calling my dbt macro `date_diff_precise`, with value returned by another macro `run_time` being the second variable `begin_date`

```
{{ date_diff_precise(time_period = "'day'",
                     begin_date = {{ run_time() }},
                     end_date = end_date,
                     return_negative_date_diff = 'FALSE') }}
```

This would raise a compilation error that

[image]

My environment: VSCode, Athena/Presto

Comment: Can you just pass macro name as in  {% macro base_macro(func1, arg1, arg2) %}
  {{ func1(arg1, arg2) }}
{% endmacro %} instead of assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

[Don't Nest Your Curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies)

```
{{ date_diff_precise(time_period = "'day'",
                     begin_date = run_time(),
                     end_date = end_date,
                     return_negative_date_diff = 'FALSE') }}
```